# Printing keys based on Hash values in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I need to print keys based on vales in hash. Here is the code, I wrote

```
foreach $value (values %hash)
{
    print "$value\t$hash{$value}\n";
}
```

Error: I can only print values, but not keys.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    print "$key\t$hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Hashes are designed to be accessed by key, not by value. You need to loop over a list of keys, not values.

Then you can use the keys to access the associated values.

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    my $value = $hash{$key};
    say "$key = \t$value";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print "$_\t$hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
map { print "$_\t$hash{$_}\n" } keys %hash;
```

Comment: You should not use `map` as a loop statement. Use a `for` loop instead. E.g. `print "$_..." for keys %hash`.

Comment: It's a simple fix - `print map { "$_\t$hash{$_}\n" } keys %hash;` :-)

Comment: @DaveCross `print "$_\t$hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash` is even simpler.

Comment: Or even `say "$_\t$hash{$_}" for keys %hash`. But I was talking about the smallest change from what s0me0ne originally had :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use while and each if you want to iterate through keys and values:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    say "$key -> $value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title requests to print key based on the value.

if your key and value in your harsh table should be one to one

```
foreach $key (keys %hash)
{
  $r_hash{$hash{$key}}=$key;
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access it by values, then define your hash as

```
$x = {  'x1' => [ 'one','x1']}   


foreach ( values %$x ) 
{                                                                                     
     foreach $m1 (@$_) { 
        print "$m1\n";
     }
}
```

Notice you can get the key from value by second member of the value array.